# Qt - What is the best way to keep a pointer to something stored in a QList?

Tags: c++, qt

I am pretty new to Qt and C++ (been working on C# and Java all my life) and I have been reading almost everywhere that I shouldn't use raw pointers anymore (beside the ones in constructors and destructors, following RAII principle).

I am okay with it but there is a problem that I cannot easily resolve without pointers.

I'll try to explain my problem.

I am creating a QList of a custom class created by me (MyClass) that will act as a model for my application:

```
QList<MyClass> modelList;
```

This QList is updated (items added, removed or updated) by a worker thread on the basis of the information arriving from the network.

So far so good.

Now I have another thread (GUI one) that has a QList of drawable items (MyDrawableItem). Each of these items has a member that must point to one of the items in the first QList (modelList), like this:

```
QList<MyDrawableItem> listToDraw;
```

where:

```
class MyDrawableItem
{
private:
    MyObject *pointedObject;

    //List of many other members related to drawing
}
```

because everytime a timer in the GUI thread expires I have to update the drawing related members on the basis of the pointed object. Must note that it is safe to keep a pointer to members of QList as stated in the documentation:

> Note: Iterators into a QLinkedList and references into heap-allocating
>   QLists remain valid as long as the referenced items remain in the
>   container. This is not true for iterators and references into a
>   QVector and non-heap-allocating QLists.
>
> Internally, QList is represented as an array of T if sizeof(T) <=
>   sizeof(void*) and T has been declared to be either a Q_MOVABLE_TYPE or
>   a Q_PRIMITIVE_TYPE using Q_DECLARE_TYPEINFO. Otherwise, QList is
>   represented as an array of T* and the items are allocated on the heap.

How could this be feasible without using pointers? Or even better what should be the best way to do this kind of work?

I found three possible solutions:

1. Instead of keeping pointedObject as member of MyDrawableItem, keep the index of the pointed object in the modelList. Then on the update go look inside the QList. But what if the item in the list is removed? I could signal it but if the update happens before the slot is called?
2. Don't keep anything at all as a member and connect two signals to MyDrawableItem. One signal is `updateDrawing(const MyObject&)` that updates the drawing-related members and another signal is `removeDrawing()` that simply deletes the object. This way I don't have to worry about the syncronization between the threads because the MyDrawableItem object won't ever look at the content of the QList. In this case I could be updating the item very often with lots of signals while I only want to update the GUI once in a while (timer of 500 ms).
3. Simply use pointers.
4. Evolve and use QSharedPointers but I have never used those and I don't know if that is the best option.

I think that neither of these solutions is the perfect one so I am here asking for your help.

How do the standard views in Qt (tableview, listview, ecc.) deal with this problem?

How should I deal with it?

Please help me, I am thinking about this from yesterday and I don't want to make a  mess.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: in general there is nothing wrong with raw pointers. What you should avoid are raw **owning** pointers. The problem with pointers to elements in containers is that some containers have to reallocate their memory when new elements are added rendering pointers to elements invalid (actually I dont know if thats the case for `QList`)

Comment: @user463035818 `QList<T>` is a vector of pointers to `T`. When resizing the `QList`, only the vector gets reallocated, not the pointed `T`s. However for small types, `QList` is optimized to store directly the `T`s inside the vector. That's why the quoted Qt Documentation makes a difference between "heap-allocating and non-heap-allocating QList".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the current trend among the C++ community, especially if you look at all the CppCon conferences to discourage the use of raw pointers.

This trend is not without sold basis, as the use of `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` as well as `std::make_unique` and `std::make_shared` can help a lot memory management and prevent some pitfalls (like having an exception thrown during a call to a constructor).

However, there is nothing absolute in this "do not use raw pointers" trend and raw pointers can still be used and smart pointers do not solve all memory management problems.

Concerning the case of Qt, if you are dealing with `QObject` derived class and you properly parent your objects you are kind of safe as you have an [owning hierarchy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html) and parents QObjects will destroy their children. This is very important if you are also using `QThread` as `QObject` instances are associated with a `QThread` and all  instances in a `QObject` hierachy are associated with the same thread.

Regarding your solutions:

1. Bad idea, you need to sync your list and the indexes all the time.
2. It could be an idea, but it changes the architecture of your software. Does MyObject really needs to know about `MyObject` ? If the answer is 'no', signal/slots seems a better solution. It might indeed require some work to solve your refresh rate issue, but this is off-topic.
3. It might look like a good idea, especially if your objects are inheriting `QObject`. Also you may want to use `QVector<T *>` and `std::vector<T *>` and let the QObject hierarchy deals with life span of your objects. You can listen to the `destroyed()` signal to know when the object are destroyed, or use `QPointer`. However, it does not solve the thread safeness on your consumer side, as the object might be deleted at any point in time from another thread.
4. If you cannot do 2, this is the option to go for. You just have to take care to not have cyclic dependencies or you will leak memory. However, this might be a bad idea if you want that when you delete an object in your list then it gets removed from your GUI object. If you simply keep a shared pointer, you will never know that it was removed from the list. As stated by @Felix, you can store weak pointers and convert them to shared pointers only when needed, but if you have consumers in multiple threads, then you may never delete the object. Also you have to make `MyObject` thread-safe as you are mutating it states from one thread and reading it from another thread. Using option 4 does change the owning model of your software: in the current state the QList owns the instances, with option 4 the ownership is shared with anyone getting a shared pointer.

My personal choice would be to replace the QList with a QVector of pointers.
If your objects inherit from QObject, then I would parent all the objects in the QVector to the object that owns the QList/QVector. This is to ensure proper parenting and thread association.
Then I would try option 2, and only if option 2 fails go for option 4.

Here is an exemple:

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyClass(QObject *parent = nullptr);

signals:
    void stateChanged(int state);
};

class Owner : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Owner(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void addObject(MyClass *obj) {
        obj->setParent(this);
        m_objects.append(obj);
    }

    void removeObject() {
        delete m_objects.takeFirst();
    }

private:
    QVector<MyClass *> m_objects;
};



class Consumer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Consumer(QObject *parent = nullptr);

public slots:
    void onStateChanged(int state) {
        m_cachedState = state;
    }

private:
    int m_cachedState = 0;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    QThread thread;
    thread.start();

    Owner owner;
    Consumer consumer;
    consumer.moveToThread(&thread);

    MyClass *object = new MyClass();
    owner.addObject(object);
    QObject::connect(object, &MyClass::stateChanged, &consumer, &Consumer::onStateChanged);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and all the details. I have a couple of questions. In the second case, my drawable object needs to know the last state of myobject. But wouldn't it be ok if I pass the state with my signal? In case 3 instead, if I use qobject hierarchy I would have a problem, because the owner of the qlist will stay alive for all the application lifetime. In this case the objects in the list will never be destroyed, right? If this wasn't the case, listening to qobject::destroyed() could lead to error if the timer signals before destroyed but the item was already removed?

Comment: How would you implement solution 3 without using qobject hierarchy?

Comment: @Lulanz I did not think about pending signals for option 3, this is indeed a problem. And yes, when you remove an object from vector, you would need to call `delete` on it, otherwise it will stay alive for as long as the parent live.

Comment: @Lulanz I edited my answer. I am now recommending option 2. To use option 3, you need to have a thread safe way of ensuring both threads stopped using an object before deleting it, it can be hard to do. Option 4 is the next best choice after option 2, but requires to make your shared class thread safe.

Comment: Thanks for the time you spent for me. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Anyway in my application I only have one consumer thread, so I could use shared/weak pointers because there won't be a chance that the item isn'5t deleted when I wish to. I took a look at the code you posted and I have a question.What if I don't have to notify only the change of a state?i'll explain what I mean. MyClass is more a struct than a class. It contains a dozen of member variables and everytime I update, it the GUI Thread must read all of them. Is it good, thinking about performance, to pass all the struct as a parameter of the signal?

Comment: @Lulanz You would have to test to know for sure. If you use signals, Qt will make a copy of your struct. If you do not want to make copy (e.g. by using shared pointers), you have to protect your data with a mutex or something like that. So you have to evaluate "Qt signals mechanism + your struct copy" vs "shared pointers + mutex protection". Depending on you large is your data, how often you will copy it and how you protect it against concurrent access (QMutex, QReadWriteLock, etc.), the results can vary a lot.

Comment: I don't know how to evaluate the complexity of the two methods... I'm sorry if I am asking all this help from you, but which road would you follow if the struct is less than 70 byte and the copy occurs once every 500 ms? Suppose that it could be that there are more than one source of update (more than a timer of 500 ms running concurrently)

Comment: @Lulanz What I was saying is that you cannot evaluate. The only solution is to test by running a benchmark and measure which way is the fastest.

Answer (score 4):

An addition to @Benjamin T's answer:

If you do decide to go for option 4 and use `QSharedPointer` (or the std variant), you can actually control ownership somewhat using "weak pointers". Weak pointers store a reference to the object, but do not own it. Once the last "strong pointer" gets destroyed, all the weak pointers drop the reference and reset themselves to `nullptr`.

For your concrete example, you could use a `QList<QSharedPointer<MyClass>>` for the model and use `QWeakPointer<MyClass>` in the drawable classes. Before drawing you would create a local `QSharedPointer<MyClass>` in the drawing function and check if it is valid.

I would still recommend you to use 2/3, as recommended by Benjamin. Just a small addition.

Comment: I did not talk about this, because if you can have situations where after your removed a shared pointer from the list, it never get destroyed because you always have a consumer that holds a shared pointer. This might be a big drawback if you want the object to be destroyed quickly and in a deterministic manner. But it still is a viable solution if you know that your consumers will rarely hold a shared pointer.

Comment: If my consumers hold a shared pointer only during the update function because they create one shared pointer from the weak one as suggested by Felix, wouldn't the object be destroyed as soon as the update function is over if the item is destroyed in the meantime?

Comment: If this is the case, wouldn't this be the best solution? And more important, is this solution thread safe? Or do I have to control the access to the pointer with mutexes?

Comment: @Lulanz `std::shared_ptr` and `QSharedPointer` are thread-safe, but it only guarantees that the object life time is handled in a thread-safe way. It offers no guarantee about the access to the pointed object members or values. Also what I was saying is, if you have 2 consumer threads, each thread holding a weak pointer to the same object, it could happen that by the time the update function terminate in one thread, it has already started again in the other thread andthus extended the lifetime of the object. Meaning that you have no guarantee that the object will be effectively destroyed.